# How to suppress a text field in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a business cards project with variable data printing done online. I need a rule I can use so that the fields that are not used or left blank will be suppressed.

At the moment I am getting a blank test field between two text fields if it is left blank. I am new to this so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by suppressed? Disabled input, not included in a validation function, not sent in some ajax request, not sent in form submission?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your situation involves a user typing data into an HTML form after which the information is displayed somehow on an HTML page.  If any of that is false, we will need more information to answer your question.  It sounds like you have already figured out how to send the information from form to display and you just want to not see empty lines of display.  That is handled with CSS style.

First, you need to have some way to test whether the field contains user input.  Since you didn't offer any code to build on, I'm going to assume for the moment that you can figure out how to do that.

Then you can use JavaScript to programmatically alter the CSS of a given element.  It will go something like this:

```
if (field_modified === false) {
    // cause an HTML element to not be displayed
    // here, the value associated to whatever field
    // you are testing is displayed in an HTML node with ID 'id_of_node_here'
    // There are various other ways of accessing specific HTML nodes
    // without giving them IDs.  You can research that yourself.
    document.getElementById('id_of_node_here').style.display = "none";
}
```

To test user input in a field, it's probably sufficient to test the length of the value or whether a form element has been changed from default.